# Paypal Recurring Payment through ACH in Php

Tags: php, paypal, payment, recurring

I have researched through the Paypal website regarding Recurring ACH payment in PHP but could not find any satisfying solution. Paypal has mentioned SDKS for C# & Java for Recurring ACH, but not for PHP at all. Is it possible to write a Recurring ACH PHP scripts for my website? Suggestions are welcome.

I have already integrated Recurring payment through Paypal pro (using Credit cards) but I want to enable the service through the ACH mode (Using Bank account) with recurring subscription. Is it possible with PHP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the Payflow system, but I do not know of any examples specifically in PHP that I have came across for this.  You would need to use one of the examples as a model and build your own code in PHP for this.

Comment: Hi Chad, Thanks for your info. yeah of course, i have read all the document provided by Paypal for PayFlow Pro API guide. but donot find the way to do it in Recurring way using PHp. One time payment kind of things, i was aware about, but did not find the way to do recurring payment through ACH specially in PHP.

Comment: There not a clear description on how to do this in the guides.  You basically have to cross reference the ACH guide, and the Recurring Billing guide.  Here is an example of what I am sending over to the test server to create an ACH RB Profile.  USER=xxxxx&VENDOR=xxxxx&PARTNER=PayPal&PWD=xxxxx&TRXTYPE=R&ACCTTYPE=C&AUTHTYPE=WEB&FIRSTNAME=Bob&TENDER=A&ACCT=6355059797&ABA=091000019&PROFILENAME=RegularSubscription&AMT=42.00&START=04202013PAYPERIOD=WEEK&TERM=12&ACTION=A